# Publishing ASP.NET Core 2.1 to Google Cloud Platform shows error: bad character range

Tags: google-app-engine, asp.net-core, google-cloud-platform, asp.net-core-2.1, app-engine-flexible

When I try to publish an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application to Google Cloud Platform App Engine I get the error gcloud crashed (error): bad character range.

I publish with the GCP Visual Studio 2017 extension and I get the above error.

I publish from the cmd with an app.yaml in my project and I get the above error.

In order to deploy the ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application to Google Cloud App Engine I added an app.yaml file with the following contents:

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

I did the following:

Added app.yaml with

```
runtime: aspnetcore
env: flex
```

Added it to csproj

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="app.yaml" CopyToOutputDirectory="Always" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And executed the command

```
gcloud beta app deploy ./bin/release/netcoreapp2.1/publish/app.yaml
```

However I got the error: gcloud crashed (error): bad character range

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I follow the following guide and still get the same error when I try method 1, 2 and 3: https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/10/4-ways-you-can-deploy-an-ASP.NET-Core-app-to-GCP.html

Comment: are you sure you don't have any non-ascii characters in the yaml file?

Comment: Ur not using azure :)

Comment: Even if I try an empty yaml file it shows the error. And the strange thing is that it also gives the error when I try it with the GCP Visual Studio extension and that is withouth the yaml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**WORKING**

I got it working with the following.

I downloaded GCP SDK 174.0.0 and then I tried it with the GCP Visual Studio extension and it showed the error:

```
{
    "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "SSL is required to perform this operation.",
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

So I turned on SSL 3.0 in my internet options and then it worked.

You need GCP SDK 174.0.0 or higher to use the GCP Visual Studio extension.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [public issue](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/112933234) for this.
It is a known issue with 213.0.0. Please try using the newest version, or version 212 if that still doesn't work.

Comment: I am working with 215.0.0 now. I will try some older versions to see if they give the same error.